# Find method of moments estimator for $\theta$ in Cauchy$(\theta,1)$ distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

> Given $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \sim $ Cauchy Distribution ${C(\theta,1)}$, what is a method of moments estimator of $\theta$?

$\theta^* = \text{mean}$ is the method of moments estimator for Cauchy Distribution.  For Cauchy Distribution Moment Generating function is not defined so can we calculate the method of moments estimator for it?

Comment: Usual sample moments like sample mean are not valid for method of moments estimation here because their mean do not exist. You can ask for a consistent estimator of $\theta$ instead. How about the sample median? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/373526/119261.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Got it thanks